# Why is it in JavaScript, to implement a hash table, ES6 map is generally faster than plain objects?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I've been grinding LeetCode these days using JavaScript. I found that if I need to implement a hash table, for example this famous question, https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/, using a ES6 `map` generally results in better speed compared to plain old javascript object, like 20ms faster.

```
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
  const map = new Map();

  for (let [index, value] of nums.entries()) {
    if (map.has(target - value)) return [map.get(target - value), index];
    map.set(value, index);
  }

};


var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
  const map = {};

  for (let [index, value] of nums.entries()) {
    if (map[target - value] !== undefined) return [map[target - value], index];
    map[value] = index;
  }
};
```

To me that the biggest use case for ES6 `Map` over plain old objects is when we want the keys not only to be strings. Can someone please explain to me why `Map` is superior in terms of speed and what are some other use cases where `Map` is better than plain old objects in JavaScript

Comment: It's probably faster because it's the data type specifically designed to be a `Map`.

Comment: @Matthew What were objects specifically designed to be? What do they do other than map strings to values? `Map` is a generalization.

Comment: Good point, never really thought of it from that perspective, I was thinking more of the object type behavior such as message passing with `this` references.

Comment: @Barmar Objects (at least small objects) are designed to be records of stable shape.

Comment: "*the case when we want the keys not only to be strings*" - and that's precisely what you are doing here? :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, the `Map` version uses numbers for keys, while the `object` version uses strings.

Converting all those numbers (like `target-value`) into strings probably accounts for most of the extra cost in the `object` version.